# Write "good" or "bad" if values in range are true or false

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I have a a column (T) with a range of values (T5 thru T35)
all the values are usually "true" but when one or more values say false, I want excel to write in cell T36 "bad". And the same thing for "true" values, if all are "true" then write in cell T36 "good".
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In T36:

```
IF(COUNTIF(T5:T35,"True")=ROWS(T5:T35),"GOOD","BAD")
```